# Loading WMS layer in R leaflet using addWMSTiles

Tags: r, leaflet, wms

I'm trying to add WMS tiles in the R leaflet package - not a problem using this example geoserver WMS:

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 4) %>%  addWMSTiles(
"http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms",
layers = "energy:energy-pop-exposure-nuclear-plants-locations_plants",
options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
tileOptions(tms = TRUE),
attribution = "")
```

However, when I try using WMS from the  [National Map](http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSHydroNHD/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS), I continue to get empty leaflet results despite multiple attempts at trying to set parameters correctly for url and layers:

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 4) %>%addWMSTiles(
"http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSHydroNHD/MapServer/WmsServer?",
layers = "0",
options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
attribution = "")
```

I've not used leaflet before outside the R leaflet package, so this may be a very novice mistake in setting my parameters in leaflet using this type of WMS

Comment: You may find [this link](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers) helpful. It seems that you need to go through a registration process for arcgis; `"in order to use ArcGIS maps, you must register and abide by the terms of service. No special syntax is required."`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to be zoomed in a little further for the layer to show up. Try this:

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 7) %>%addWMSTiles(
"http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/USGSHydroNHD/MapServer/WMSServer?",
layers = "0",
options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
attribution = "")
```

Comment: do you know how to remove the WMS tile?